# Use Mosaico or easy editor to edit email system template

Tags: civievent, civimail, mosaico

I'm using 4.7.29 CiviCRM with latest Wordpress version.

Is it possible to edit email template (i.e. "Events - Registration Confirmation and Receipt (on-line)") with Mosaico ? Or with another extension ?

Because edit email template seems to be an horrific work...
I don't know where begin to edit template, there are too much conditional and informations...

In the event configuration, it should be possible to choose which template to use for which event for registration confirmation.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in Civi that provides this, and no Extensions I am aware of that provide this. No it cannot be done using Mosaico.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't know of any extension that does that - it's all hand editing code. And no, you can't select a template on an event. The template that is there is the receipt for all events. If you want to send an additional email after people register, you can do this using the extension CiviRules.

Comment: or Scheduled Reminders?

Comment: Scheduled reminders only work based on "x" number of days before/after an event's start or end date. Since they're talking about the automated email that goes out after you register, it sounds like they need something that goes out right away. I wish they would add the ability to send a scheduled reminder based on how long it's been since they registered. We're having to do the same setup with CiviRules to send out a secondary email that gives them information to prepare for the training they signed up for.

Comment: i thought it could be set to eg 0 hours. Maybe that is only for Memberships etc?

Comment: Memberships have different settings in scheduled reminders than events. Memberships are in relation to the membership join or end date. Events are in relation to the start or end date of the event. I was told you could likely use the contribution setting, as then you can go by what event type, name, etc you have to distinguish them. I haven't tested this yet, but it's on my to do list this week. So I'm not 100% on whether it actually works that way.